# Why is $x(t) = \frac {x_n + x_{n+1}}{2}$ when proving the Euler-Lagrange Equation?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, discrete, lattice-model

When proving the Euler-Lagrange Equation for a single degree of freedom, we replace continuous time with stroboscopic time. We replace $$\dot x=\frac{x_{n+1}-x_n}{\Delta t}$$
 but why do we replace $$x(t) = \frac {x_n + x_{n+1}}{2}$$
Can't we just write it as $$x(t)=x_n$$ for every position of $\Delta t?$

Comment: $x_{n+1}-x_n \rightarrow O(\Delta t) \rightarrow 0$. Therefore $x_n + x_{n+1} = 2 x_n + (x_{n+1} - x_n) \rightarrow 2 x_n $ so it does not matter